# Accessing com.sun.tools.javac.util from Java 9

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, sun

I'm trying to access the `List` class from `com.sun.tools.javac.util`. This works fine with Java 8, but when switching to Java 9 I get the following error: `Package 'com.sun.tools.javac.util' is declared in module "jdk.compiler", which does not export it to the unnamed module"`.

I tried adding `requires jdk.compiler;` to my `module-info` file, but this did not solve the issue.

Comment: What functionality of the class are you using?

Comment: In JDK9 you need to use [`javax.tools`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html). Classes from unexported packages are unavailable.

Comment: @nullpointer I'm using to for code generation, but I also need other classes from this package

Comment: @M.leRutte using another package is not the solution since they're simply not the same

Comment: @bramhaag the package has been deprecated in Java 9. you shall migrate to their equivalent implementations which could be depicted looking at your code itself.

Comment: Well, `com.sun.*` packages have been "forbidden" for a while now since they're elligible for change or even removal (aka deprecation) in every Java version. You still could access them but it's generally not advisable to do so.

Comment: @nullpointer I fail to find an equivalent, the compiler is also still using this package internally.

Comment: I just looked up that class and didn’t see anything that explains why a developer could *need* that list class instead of just using, e.g. `ArrayList` or one of the specialized lists returned by the standard factory methods.

Comment: FWIW, this class was written in the 1.2 days by Martin Odersky (designer of Scala). Early versions of Scala's List looked very similar.

Comment: Comment near the top of the file: "This is NOT part of any supported API. If you write code that depends on this, you do so at your own risk. This code and its internal interfaces are subject to change or deletion without notice." http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/langtools/file/jdk-9+181/src/jdk.compiler/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/util/List.java#l48

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the longer run, the safe way to be dealing with such situation is to move away from using these internal APIs of the JDK.

One can make use of the **[`jdk.compiler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.compiler/module-summary.html)** module's APIs as a replacement to the *[`com.sun.tools.javac`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk.compiler-summary.html)* package.

> Defines the implementation of the [system Java compiler](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) and its command
> line equivalent, ***javac***, as well as ***javah***.

Specifically for *`com.sun.tools.javac.util.List`*, almost all of its non-overridden, self-defined methods could be derived from the implementation based on the interface **[`java.util.List`.](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/List.html)**

---

[Migration guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F7696E02-A1FB-4D5A-B1F2-89E7007D4096)'s column about *Removed `java.*` APIs* state that -

> The Java team is committed to backward compatibility. If an
> application runs in JDK 8, then it will run on JDK 9 as long as it
> uses APIs that are supported and intended for external use.
>
> These include:
>
> - JCP standard, **`java.*`**, **`javax.*`**
> - JDK-specific APIs, some **`com.sun.*`**, some **`jdk.*`**
>
> ***Supported APIs can be removed from the JDK, but only with notice.*** Find out if your code is using deprecated APIs by running
> the static analysis tool *`jdeprscan`*.

Then to add to the highlighted risk above..

### Compile Time

Internal APIs that are encapsulated in JDK 9 are not accessible at compile time, but can be made accessible at compile time via the `--add-exports` command-line option.

In your case :

```
--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

### Run Time

At the runtime, they remain accessible if they were in JDK 8 but in a future release, they will become inaccessible, at which point the `--add-exports` or `--add-opens` options can be used to make them accessible at runtime as well.

Comment: These APIs aren't deprecated; they're merely internal interfaces of javac that are now inaccessible by default in JDK 9. Otherwise, yes.

Comment: @StuartMarks Agreed. *Internal API* seems a better term than *deprecated*? Just to clarify, I didn't mean `@Deprecated` anyway though.

Comment: Yes, *internal* is preferable. None of this stuff has been deprecated. Thanks for updating.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @StuartMarks :)

Comment: where do i type this command "--add-exports jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED"?

Comment: @Derek you need to pass that as a  javac argument while compiling and as a JVM argument during runtime.

Comment: @Osama Jamal, in .idea/compiler.xml if you use IntelliJ Idea or Android Studio (for visibility in source code) and in build.gradle of your module (to work in compile time)