# Maven install error with mule, com.sun.tools.jar not found in jdk

Tags: java, maven, mule, anypoint-studio, java-11

When I try to make a maven clean install I get this errors:

[image]

I have looked for this error on other posts, and they say to use jdk instead of jre or that the path is bad, but none of those is my problem.

This project is Mule Aplication made with Anypoint Studio.

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing com.sun.tools.javac.util from Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773519/accessing-com-sun-tools-javac-util-from-java-9)

Comment: It is not that problem

Comment: It looks exactly like that cause you are using JDK 11 which does not have a tools.jar anymore ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your output I can see you are using Java 11. Mule does not support java 11 yet.
Mule 4.2 will support Java 11 when released.

For now you need to use jdk 8.

https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/Mule-Runtime-support-for-Java-11-FAQ