# How to add modules export to jdk 11 using maven ? I've using jdk 11.0.18 and my maven version is 3.5.4

Tags: maven, java-11

Whenever Im trying to import it using maven it says below.

(package com.sun.tools.javac.tree is declared in module jdk.compiler, which does not export it to module ALL_UNNAMED)

added modules tag and exported but still issue still persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing com.sun.tools.javac.util from Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46773519/accessing-com-sun-tools-javac-util-from-java-9)

Comment: @seenukarthi Nope. I'm not getting help from it. As I am migrating project from java 8 to java 11. Whenever Im trying to add this export in Intellij Idea. It's working perfectly fine but Im not getting it whenever Im doing it locally without using any IDE. hence I need more visibility on Where should I give the module exports in my pom.xml Thanks for the help!

Comment: You might need to update your maven version to support the add modules args.

Comment: @Naman I did but still failed. I updated it to 3.9.5 still it failed.

Comment: I tried to add the compilerArgs through the maven code but still no success. Can someone please check this.

Comment: you need to add details to the question, configurations as specified, relevant code, and method of execution so that one can attempt to reproduce the issue and help you further.

Comment: Can Someone mark it resolved as I am able to resolve this error.